# Como fazer o cadastro de uma chave estrangeira que está em outra tela no php?

Tags: php, chave-estrangeira

Como faço para gravar o id_usuario do usuário que está logado, e o id_endereco da classe de endereco na tabela de denuncia?

OBS: as chaves primárias das classe estão automáticas no banco de dados

Classe Login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($conexao, "projeto");
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cadastro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            function sucesso() {
                setTimeout("window.location='telaLogin.php'", 2000);
            }

        </script>
        <?php
        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $password = md5($password);
        $email = $_POST["email"];

        $inserir = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, username, password, email) 
        VALUES ('$nome', '$username', '$password', '$email');";
        mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
        echo"Usuario cadastrado com sucesso. Redirecionando para tela de login em 2 segundos.";
        echo"<script language='javascript'>sucesso()</script";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

tela denuncia:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($conexao, "projeto");
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cadastro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="javascript">
            function sucesso(){
                setTimeout("window.location='telaInicial2.php'", 2000);
            }
            
        </script>
    <?php
        $descricaoProblema = $_POST["descricaoProblema"];
        $dicaSolucao = $_POST["dicaSolucao"];
            
        $inserir = "INSERT INTO denuncia (descricaoProblema, dicaSolucao, Usuario_id, Endereco_id, Status_id) 
        VALUES ('$descricaoProblema', '$dicaSolucao', '1');";
        mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
        echo"Denuncia cadastrada com sucesso. Redirecionando para tela inicial em 1 segundos.";
        echo"<script language='javascript'>sucesso()</script";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Classe de endereco:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($conexao, "projeto");
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cadastro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="javascript">
            function sucesso(){
                setTimeout("window.location='telaDenuncia.php'", 2000);
            }
            
        </script>
    <?php
        $local = $_POST["local"];
        $estado = $_POST["estado"];
        $cidade = $_POST["cidade"];
        $bairro = $_POST["bairro"];
        $rua = $_POST["rua"];
        $telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
            
        $inserir = "INSERT INTO endereco (local, estado, cidade, bairro, rua, telefone) 
        VALUES ('$local', '$estado', '$cidade', '$bairro', '$rua', '$telefone');";
        mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
        echo"Endereco cadastrado com sucesso. Redirecionando para cadastro da denuncia em 2 segundos.";
        echo"<script language='javascript'>sucesso()</script";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Scripts sql:

```
create table usuario(
idUsuario serial,
nome varchar(60) not null,
username varchar(60) not null,
password varchar(200) not null,
email varchar(20) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (idUsuario) 
)Engine=InnoDB;

alter table usuario add constraint unique_username unique(username);

create table endereco(
idEndereco serial,
local varchar(60) not null,
estado varchar(40) not null,
cidade varchar(40) not null,
bairro varchar(60) not null,
rua varchar(60) not null,
telefone varchar(15) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(idEndereco)
)Engine=InnoDB;

create table denuncia(
idDenuncia serial,
descricaoProblema varchar(200),
dicaSolucao varchar(200),
Usuario_id BIGINT UNSIGNED ,
Endereco_id BIGINT UNSIGNED ,
Status_id int(20),
FOREIGN KEY (Usuario_id)REFERENCES usuario (idUsuario),
FOREIGN KEY (Endereco_id)REFERENCES endereco (idEndereco),
FOREIGN KEY (Status_id)REFERENCES status (idStatus) 
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

O ID gerado pela última query, se for `AUTO_INCREMENT`, é retornado por `mysqli_insert_id`, assim:

```
mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir)
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
```

Outra forma, se usar o objeto `mysqli`, seria usando o `insert_id`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Tabela VALUES (1)";
$mysqli->query($query);
$id = $mysqli->insert_id
```

Então pode usar esse ID na próxima query quer precisar dele como *foreign key*

Mais detalhes e exemplos na documentação do php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: E como faço pra chamar esse atributo $id em outra classe?

Comment: vai precisar passar por parâmetro se os comandos de `insert` estão em classes separadas

Comment: Estão em classes separadas, consegue me mostrar como fazer isso nas classes de login e de denuncia? procurei em vários locais e não consegui resolver. Sou iniciante em php

Comment: Segua abaixo o link do projeto no git --> https://github.com/Matheus-maas/SistemaDenuncia001